# Discrete Math Strings of length 10 (Logical Question)

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics

### Original Question:

For the strings of length 10 in how many
have:

- a) four O's, three 1 's, and three 2'?
- b) at least eight l's ?
- c) weight 4 ?

### Textbook Solution:

a) 10!/4!3!3! (arrangements with repeated symbols)

b)$10\choose8$$2^2$ + $10\choose9$$2^1$ + $10\choose10$$2^0$

c)$10\choose4$(four 1's, six 0's) + $10\choose2$$8\choose1$ (two 1's, one 2, seven 0's) + $10\choose2$(two 2's, eight 0's)

### Textbook's Background Information: (Hint)

- Assume the string is the length 10, and it is made of 0's, 1's, and 2's.
- "In general, if n is any positive integer, then by the rule of product there are $3^n$ strings of length n for the alphabet 0, 1, 2".
- "If x = x 1 x2 x3 · · · Xn is one of these strings, we define the
  weight ofx, denoted wt(x), bywt(x) = x 1 + x2 + x3 + · · · + Xn. For example, wt(l2) = 3
  and wt(22) = 4 for the case where n = 2; wt(101) = 2, wt(210) = 3, and wt(222) = 6 for
  n = 3".

### Personal Logical Question:

I have problem understanding the solution and logic for part C.
My guess would be weight of 4 is referring to four 1's or two 1's and one 2's or two 2's. Am I right ?

Comment: I provided my textbook's background information, so those helpful people who want to clarify part c for me have an easier time understanding what is the question asking me. There is no useless information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight is just the sum of the entries in the string.  It appears that the strings are only composed of $0,1,2$, though you don't say that.  In that case, a weight of four can then be achieved by four $1$s, a $2$ and two $1$s, or two $2$s and the rest zeros.  The text is counting the number of ways to positions those in a string of $10$ for each case.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I just didn't understand what you mean here: "The text is counting the number of ways to positions those in a string of 10 for each case".

Comment: For one two and two ones, there also seven zeros to make a string of length ten.  The ${10 \choose 2}$ is the number of ways to place the ones in the string and the $8 \choose 1$ is the number of ways to place the two in what is left.  It gives the same result as $\frac {10!}{2!1!7!}$ following the logic in a

Comment: How would we express the final answer, $10\choose4$(four 1's, six 0's) + $10\choose2$$8\choose1$ (two 1's, one 2, seven 0's) + $10\choose2$(two 2's, eight 0's), in the form of arrangements with repeated symbols like this one --> 10!/2!1!7!   ?

Comment: Just use the formula for [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), so ${10 \choose 4}=\frac {10!}{4!6!}$  You will still have a sum of three terms of that sort.

Comment: Yeah right, I just made a minor mistake, but it gives the right answer.